# How to make child element not effected by parent element transform

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div that is a tilted box using skew transform. And I also have a child element contains text, but it also get tilted. I tried doing transform: none for the child but it didn't work. (Using svelte)

```
<div class="tilt">
    <p class="remove-tilt">Hello</p>
</div>

<style>
    .tilt {
        transform: skew(-5deg);
    }

    .remove-tilt {
        transform: none;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: A child is always affected by the parent, but sometimes you can use a reverse transform on the child (probably most of the answers you'll get). Maybe consider restructuring into "non-tilted parent" that contains "background that is tilted" + "p which is not tilted"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neutralize the transformation:

```
.remove-tilt {

   transform: skew(5deg);

}
```

It's probably best to target each element with better selectors.

```
div .tilt:not(p) {

   transform: skew(-5deg);

}
```